# How to define custom handler for Lithium layout

Tags: php, lithium

I'm looking to define my own custom handler in the layout view, much like `$this->title()` or `$this->scripts()` so that I can render content in the layout that is supplied by the view.

To be precise, I'd like to display the date of a newspaper edition in a part of the view that's defined in the `default.html.php` file. In the layout, I'd like to use `<?= $this->date(); ?>` and then, use something like

`<?= $this->html->date('Jan 1, 2013', ['inline' => false]); ?>`

in the `views/posts/view.html.php` file. The `lithium\template\view\Renderer` class appears to have methods for creating handlers (e.g., `Renderer::applyHandler`), but I can't seem to get it to work like the built-in handlers, like `$this->title()` etc. Online documentation says little about customizing the handlers in the Renderer/View classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done without subclassing the `lithium\template\view\Renderer` class. In the `media.php` bootstrap, use the `'handlers'` key with `Media::type()` to pass a customized handler to the renderer:

```
    Media::type('html', 'text/html', [
        'view' => 'lithium\template\View',
        'handlers' => ['date' => function($date) use (&$ctx) {
            if (!is_null($date)) {
                $ctx['date'] = $date;
            }
            return $ctx['date'];
        }]
    ]);
```

Then, `$this->date()` becomes available in the views and layouts, e.g.:

```
    //in the default.html.php layout

    echo $this->date(); //value passed from /views/controller/index.html.php

    //in the views/controller/index.html.php

    $this->date(date('Y-m-d'));
```

As a side note, the `$ctx` variable is necessary for accessing the rendering context; see the `lithium\template\view\Renderer::_init()` method for where the `'handlers'` array gets merged with the rendering context.

Answer (score 0):

This is solved using [helpers](http://lithify.me/docs/lithium/template)
The documentation under **Creating custom helpers** should be sufficient.

Comment: I'm not sure how helpers accomplish what I'm looking for. In this example, I'm essentially displaying a variable in the layout that is defined in the view. Take `$this->html->style('styles', ['inline' => false])` for instance. If you look at this helper method, it's mapping a filename onto the rendering context so that the layout can display the stylesheets defined in the view (not layout) with `$this->styles()`. These handlers are defined in the Renderer class. I'd like to add custom handlers, and I don't see how the helper classes accomplish this without getting a little hackish...